# Error while composing two functions

Tags: haskell, function-composition

I try to compose two function with type specifying.

```
foo :: Num a => a -> a
foo a = a + 2

bar :: Num a => a -> a
bar a = a * 2

fooBarCompose :: (Num a, Num b, Num c) => (a -> b) -> (c -> a) -> c -> b
fooBarCompose f g = f . g
```

My module compiles, but in runtime when I invoke

```
fooBarCompose bar foo
```

I get an error:

```
No instance for (Show (b0 -> b0))
  (maybe you haven't applied enough arguments to a function?)
  arising from a use of ‘print’
In the first argument of ‘print’, namely ‘it’
In a stmt of an interactive GHCi command: print it
```

Any ideas why I get this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Any ideas why I get this?

*You don't*. Everything you've written works just fine. You can use `fooBarCompose bar foo` in any program you want.

Only, if you try to *evaluate* it in GHCi, it has a problem: `fooBarCompose bar foo` is a function. How the heck is it supposed to *show a function*? Display an exhaustive list of all possible inputs and corresponding results? Clearly not feasible. GHCi uses [`print`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Prelude.html#v:print) under the hood, which simply invokes [`show`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Prelude.html#v:show). And, well, because *it's not possible* to show a function, it gives you an error message saying exactly this.

OTOH, the result of applying a function to *any single value* can easily be shown, e.g.

```
> fooBarCompose bar foo 2  -- aka `bar . foo $ 2`
8
```